# How to fix font baseline in Android Lollipop when working with custom icon fonts?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, font-awesome, android-5.0-lollipop

I am currently using FontAwesome in one of my Android projects. I primarily use it to display icons to the left of text on certain buttons. I noticed that since upgrading one of my test devices to Lollipop, the icons began sagging below the baseline of the text on the button.
Please see the images below:

### Android KitKat (Nexus 7) - good:

[image: KitKat]

### Android Lollipop (Nexus 4) - bad:

[image: Lollipop]

Please note that the bottom of the icon in the first image sits on the baseline of the text, while the bottom of the icon in the second image is below the baseline.

### Code:

```
<string name="button_text_logout"> LOG OUT</string>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_menu_item"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/button_text_logout"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/action_item_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/action_item_padding"/>

Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
logOutTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

I am using the [fa-sign-out](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/sign-out/) icon. The code works fine on all devices running versions of Android prior to 5.0. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: A nasty way would be to have two versions, one for less than 5.0 and one for greater or equal to 5.0. But there must be a better way.

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing that. I can, of course, split all text views into two, then move the icon up by a couple of dps. However, this becomes a problem when dealing with buttons. I would like to avoid creating custom views, if possible.

Comment: late but may help someone, Once resolved this issue using android:includeFontPadding="false"

Comment: @QAMAR you should make this into an answer and it should be made an accepted answer. This fixed the issue for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

late but may help someone, Once resolved this issue using `android:includeFontPadding="false"`